# MySql executing Set and Concat statements in VB.net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to get some values - columns as rows and viceversa - from MySQL to show on a `DataGridView`. I have this code, that should be run in MySQL-

```
SET @header = CONCAT('SELECT \'sl\', ',
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(' \'', sl, '\'')) FROM cars where sl=1),
    ' LIMIT 0, 0');

SET @a = -1;
SET @line1 = CONCAT(
    'SELECT \'Plate\',',
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(' (SELECT Plate FROM cars LIMIT ',
                @a:=@a+1,
                ', 1)')
            )
        FROM cars where sl=1
    ));

SET @a := -1;
SET @line2 = CONCAT(
    'SELECT \'Brand\',',
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(' (SELECT Brand FROM cars LIMIT ',
                @a:=@a+1,
                ', 1)')
            )
        FROM cars where sl=1
    ));

SET @query = CONCAT('(',
    @header,
    ') UNION (',
    @line1,
    ') UNION (',
    @line2,
    ')'
);

PREPARE my_query FROM @query;
EXECUTE my_query;
```

Now when I try to run this via the `ExecuteNonQuery` command by saving all this code in a string, I get a `MySQLException` error- `Fatal error encountered during command execution.`

I have tried to split the code into separate strings, but the same error popped. Also tried to increase the `CommandTimeout`, but nothing worked.

Is there any special way to run these statements? Or is there any problem with the code? Please note that this runs effectively without any error on the command line client.

PS: The code is used from Q# 3288014 - Thanks to Anax

**EDIT:**

I found a work around to the same thing, but all done in VB.

```
Dim sa() As String = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
Dim sa2() As String = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
connect()
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
execstr = "describe cars"
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(execstr, connection)
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Dim i As Integer = 0
While reader.Read
    sa(i) = reader.GetString(0)
    i = i + 1
End While
reader.Close()
connection.Close()
connect()
execstr = "select*from cars where sl=1;"
Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand(execstr, connection)
reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
While reader.Read
   For i1 As Integer = 0 To sa.Length - 1
        sa2(i1) = reader.GetString(i1)
   Next
End While
reader.Close()
connection.Close()
reader.Close()
connection.Close()
Dim t As New DataTable
t.Columns.Add(sa(0))
t.Columns.Add(sa2(0))
For y As Integer = 1 To sa.Length - 1
    t.Rows.Add(sa(y), sa2(y))
Next
DataGridView1.DataSource = t
```

Funny to find that what all can be done in a string in MySQL, takes so much code in VB.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in a single or series of `ExecuteNonQuery` command(s).  This example was showing the code you would put in a stored procedure on mysql.  The you call the stored procedure using a DataAdapter or DataReader.

Comment: You can't run these commands directly. You must either create a stored procedure in the database to do this as shown or you might be able to break-down the peices to do this in VB, since it is just building a string.  ...

Comment: Dim s as string = "'SELECT \'Plate\',',
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(' (SELECT Plate FROM cars LIMIT ',
                @a:=@a+1,
                ', 1)')
            )
        FROM cars where sl=1
    )"

Comment: And then keep adding to the variable using `s &= "More SQL"`

Comment: Post the code you tried, as an EDIT to your original post. Also include EXACT error and line you got the error on.

Comment: Never mind. I did a workaround. First, I ran a `describe table_name` statement, and put all results in a string `array`, then the `select` statement results in another string `array`, created a `datatable`, ran some `for` magic and done.